# What are the components of registration id in Google Cloud Messaging?

Tags: android

1. question:

I ask myself if a google cloud messaging message does include any target application, so only the app can get the message? so could it be possible that application x can receive the google cloud messaging message what is adressed to application y on my device?

2. question:

Google says that when GCM Message is sent, it is sent to the android device, - but what role does play the play store library u need to use gcm? what compontent of system does exactly receive that gcm message, the play store api?

3. question:

What components does the registration id containt so it is unique? so when gcm sends message to a reg-id, does it adress the "android-device" itself? or the google account user? or both?  thank you

Comment: Given that a number of your questions are answered in the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html and specifically the Client setup: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html perhaps it might be better to start there.

Comment: So:

2) The Google Play Service is responsible for receiving GCM Messages
3) "In other words, a registration ID is tied to a particular Android application running on a particular device" But is meant with particular device? google account? or what?

Comment: See: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#unreg

Comment: ok, it maps to a particular app on particular device - but what is meant with  device, what information of "device" is used, imei?

Comment: Probably a Google Play Services UUID, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id for the history on unique device id for Android.

Comment: hmm thank you - so is it right, that my gcm client, my application which uses gcm and have broadcast receivers, receives the broadcast from the google play service? what component does send the broadcast ?